# How to add two buttons and one label properly in one line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uibutton

I have a custom TableViewCell as this:

[image]

`name` and `event` are two buttons. Name of buttons will be assigned dynamically in the code as this:

```
[cell.newsEventName setTitle:event[@"name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.newsEventName setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Sometimes these names are too long and sometimes are short. How can I dynamically put them in one line to avoid this:

[image]

If I draw buttons too big to avoid dots then for short names I have so much empty space left. How can I place them nicely with these conditions?

Comment: The cell width is fixed, my advice is to remove the black label as it is kind of redundant in the UI the resize name to have all the space that you saved by removing the black label.

Comment: "joined your event" can be replaced with small image that is appears over the left image

Answer (score 1):

Are you using constraints? For the label that grows/shrinks, you can set it content hugging priority higher, and it will always grow.

If you are not using constraints, you can make it size to fit, or just re-do the size dynamically when the cell does it's layout

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UIStackView.  This will allow you to dynamically resize the buttons.  However, you'll only be compatable with iOS 9 if you do so.  You can add a stackview just like you add any other element in interface builder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried AutoLayout. Try AutoLayout in your custom cell for fixing positions of subviews in cell. 
Instead of fixing the width of button give its position in the cell.
Hope this solves your problem.
You can refer this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it down into 3 steps

- A: Find the required size for name

  ```
  CGSize sizeMax = CGSizeMake(cell.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
  CGSize sizeExpected = [stringName sizeWithFont:buttonName.titleLabel.font
                             constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
  float buttonWidth = sizeExpected.width;
  ```
- B: set the width of button (with name)

  ```
  CGRect r1 = cell.newsEventName.frame;
  cell.newsEventName setFrame:CGRectMake(r1.origin.x, r1.origin.y, buttonWidth, r1.size.height);
  ```
- C: set the width of label

  ```
  CGRect r2 = cell.newsEventLabel.frame;
  cell.newsEventLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(r1.origin.x+buttonWidth, r2.origin.y, r2.size.width, r2.size.height);
  ```